# Select latest and earliest times within a time group and a pivot statement

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, pivot, aggregate-functions

I have attandance data that contains a username, time, and status (`IN` or `OUT`). I want to show attendance data that contains a name, and the check in/out times. I expect a person to check in and out no more than twice a day. The data looks like this:

[image: Commercial Photography]

As you can see, my problem is that one person can have multiple data entries in different seconds for the same login attempt. This is because I get data from a fingerprint attendace scanner, and the machine in some cases makes multiple entries, sometimes just within 5-10 seconds. I want to select the data to be like this:

[image: Commercial Photography]

How can I identify the proper time for the login attempt, and then select the data with a pivot?

Comment: How many in/out paris can you have each day?  What are the rules for ignoring multiple ins/outs in a row?

Comment: Why is Doe's second `IN` time not being shown?  I see no logic for this expected output.

Comment: each person can IN/OUT up to 4 times

Comment: @Tim - because Doe have 2 IN, 07:31:35 and 07:31:43 and i just want the latest data

Comment: the rules for ignoring multiple ins/out in a row is : if multiple in/out rows have a different in 1 minutes and the latest data is taken

Comment: Why are the middle two values empty in your sample results?  How do you determine what values go in what columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to normalize your data by removing the duplicate entries. In your situation, that's a challenge because the duplicated data isn't easily identified as a duplicate. You can make some assumptions though. Below, I assume that no one will make multiple login attempts in a two minute window. You can do this by first using a Common Table Expression (CTE, using the `WITH` clause).

Within the CTE, you can use the `LAG` function. Essentially what this code is saying is "for each partition of user and entry type, if the previous value was within 2 minutes of this value, then put a number, otherwise put null." I chose null as the flag that will keep the value because `LAG` of the first entry is going to be null. So, your CTE will just return a table of entry events (ID) that were distinct attempts.

Now, you prepare another CTE that a `PIVOT` will pull from that has everything from your table, but only for the entry IDs you cared about. The `PIVOT` is going to look over the MIN/MAX of your IN/OUT times.

```
WITH UNIQUE_LOGINS AS (
    SELECT ID FROM LOGIN_TABLE 
    WHERE CASE WHEN LAG(TIME, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY USERNAME, STATUS ORDER BY TIME) 
              + (2/60/24) < TIME THEN NULL ELSE 1 END IS NULL ),   -- Times within 2 minutes
TEMP_FOR_PIVOT AS (
    SELECT USERNAME, TIME, STATUS FROM LOGIN_TABLE WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM UNIQUE_LOGINS)
)
SELECT * FROM TEMP_FOR_PIVOT
PIVOT (
    MIN(TIME), MAX(TIME) FOR STATUS IN ('IN', 'OUT')
)
```

From there, if you need to rearrange or rename your columns, then you can just put that last `SELECT` into yet another CTE and then select your values from it. There is some more about `PIVOT` here: [Rotate/pivot table with aggregation in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929108/rotate-pivot-table-with-aggregation-in-oracle)

Comment: sorry for late, i tried now and theres an error says :  ORA-30483: window  functions are not allowed here, i think error is in WITH AS